# How to run testng with command line in parallel

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am running Testcases in selenium with testng framework.
By eclipse I can run all xml together But How I can rum by command line or bat file.

I have tried with

```
start java -ea -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "/D:/Eclipse 3.6.2/eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.8.6.20141201_2240/lib/testng.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\bin;D:\XML\SpringIntegration\lib\SeleniumServer.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration\lib\selenium-java-2.37.0.zip;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\lib\sikuli-script.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\lib\sikuli-ide.jar;D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\build.xml" org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG -serport 28844 -d D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\test-output D:\XML\SpringIntegration_NIC\new_temp\TestNG_parallel.xml
```

Using Eclipse I can run all testcase correctly. but while running using this command directly its giving errors, in terms of actual testcases are not running only @BeforeSuits and @Aftersuits are running.

And I am observing strange behavior is some times it runs perfectly; But Very Rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. method one 
   create a main class like below and add Test cases classe

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();

   myTestNG.setTestClasses(new Class[]{testcasesClass1.class});

   myTestNG.run();
   }
2. there is another way.

Step (i)-
configure testng.xml as

'<'  suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="3"  '>'

// remove 2 single quotes for angular braces in begin and end

```
<classes> 
    <class name="com.test.component1.Class1Test" ></class> 
    <class name="com.test.component1.Class2Test" ></class> 
    <class name="com.test.component1.Class3Test" ></class> 

</classes>
```

Step (ii)-

run from command prompt like
java -cp lib*;bin;selenium* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

where

lib- is location of selenium libs

bin- is location your test code class files [Class1Test,Class2Test,Class3Test]

Note:- 
your project structure should be like

bin

lib

testng.xml

These all should be under same directory or pass as per location in command